# Migrating problem using psql array for pq to pgx

Tags: postgresql, go, pgx

Here is my old code:

```golang
cardinalPoints := []string{"75101", "75110", "75112", "75115", "92062"}
query = `SELECT * FROM  "DataCom_travel" WHERE ((com1 = $1 AND com2 IN ($2)) OR (com1 IN ($2) AND com2 = $1));`
err := db.Select(&dataComTravel, query, "92050", pq.Array(cardinalPoints))
```

How to do it with pgx?

pgx.Array seems not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pq.Array` will work with pgx as well. This is because all it does is provide an `sql.Scanner/driver.Valuer` implementation wrapping regular go slices. These are generic interfaces.

If you didn’t want to import both pgx and pq, you could copy the `pq.Array` and related code over to your project and create your own version. Just make sure the licensing of pq allows for that.

EDIT: Also, just read [this](https://godoc.org/github.com/jackc/pgx#hdr-Array_Mapping), which says that pgx supports string slice mapping directly. So using plain `cardinalPoints` should work.